# How to sort numerical data coming out of Grakn

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have numerical data coming out of grakn with a query that looks like this:

```
match 
$b isa component, has score $sc; 
get $sc;
```

`score` has been defined like this:

```
score sub attribute, datatype double;
```

Now I want to take the output from $sc and sort this ascending and descending. How to do this with Graql?

Answer (score 0):

The answers of a `get` can be sorted using `sort` as follows:

```
match
$b isa component, has score $sc;
get $sc;
sort $sc asc;
```

Replace `asc` with `desc` for a descending sort order.